# canvg() issue with overlapping tspan

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvg, tspan

I need to convert an svg element to png.
   while converting to png the text is getting overlapped and not aligning properly.

The actual image is like this:
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn2qK.png)

The Image after conversion is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rltMg.png)

The code is something like this:

//This piece of code comes under svg element

```
<text class="foreignObject" text-anchor="middle" x="43.37111015014165" dy="0" width="85.7422203002833" clip-path="url(#area_clip392N6)" y="1em" iname="0" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="0em">data for area map</tspan>
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="1.1em">from backend -</tspan>
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="2.2em">data for area map</tspan>
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="3.3000000000000003em">from backend -</tspan>
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="4.4em">data for area map</tspan>
<tspan x="43.37111015014165" y="1em" dy="5.5em">from backend</tspan>
</text>
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//This is the code which I used to convert svg to png:

```
 var c = document.createElement('canvas');
     c.width = item.clientWidth;
     c.height = item.clientHeight;
     canvg(c, angular.element(item).find("svg").parent().html());
    imgData['url'] = c.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Comment: I have not updated the canvg.js file before.Now I have updated and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not updated the canvg.js file before.Now I have updated and it is working fine.